# Copying string from argv to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, copy

I have following code which copy argument string to char array.

```
char *str = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
strcpy(str, argv[1]);

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Why when I pass following argument:

```
$6$4MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr$cvtrefr
```

I get:

```
MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr
```

Instead of whole string. Somewhere I lose first number. I tried various of method and every one works the same or doesn't work either.

My key is get only salt(in this case) `4MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr` or `$6$4MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr`
without third $ character. I try to also get method to copy string while I meet the third $ and then stop copying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because in the string `$6$4MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr$cvtrefr`, the `$6`, `$4` and `$cvtrefr` are expanded by the shell for positional arguments and variables and they are all empty.

Pass the argument with single quotes:

```
./a.out '$6$4MfvmFOaDUaa5bfr$cvtrefr'
```

which will prevent the shell expansion.